# Why does mdraid resync after a grow operation?

Tags: linux, mdadm

I recently decided to expand a NAS that's configured with mdadm raid1 volumes. Because disk slots are limited, the procedure for this is roughly:

1. pull one of the disks and replace it with a larger one
2. issue `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sda1`
3. wait for the resync to complete onto the new disk
4. pull the other disk and replace it
5. issue `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1`
6. wait for the resync to complete
7. issue `mdadm /dev/md0 --grow --size=max`

Step 7 is necessary because otherwise md0 will remain the old size, even though it's now entirely on larger disks.

My question is, why does `mdadm` need to resync again after step 7? What data is it syncing, from where to where? All the data that was on the old volume was fully synced during the resyncs following steps 2 and 5, so the only data that's new after step 7 is whatever garbage was on the latter portions of the replacement disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even the "garbage" on the RAID 1 needs to be the same. It's the same resync that happens after creating MD arrays, see [Initial Array Creation](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Initial_Array_Creation) on Kernel Wiki.

The biggest reason for the initial resync (and resync after grow) is to make check and repair work -- differences between legs would cause errors during checks.

If you are sure the contents of the disks is the same (they were zeroed for example) you can use `--assume-clean` with the grow operation. From mdadm manpage:

> When  an  array  is resized to a larger size with --grow --size= the new space is normally resynced in that
> same way that the whole array is resynced at creation.  From Linux version 3.0, --assume-clean can be  used
> with that command to avoid the automatic resync.

Comment: Makes sense.

Is the system just copying the garbage from one disk onto the other, then? How does it decide which garbage to use?

Comment: I guess mdadm picks the first disk in the array (which is the first one found during assemble, `mdadm --detail` contains disk numbers in its output) but I'm not sure.